# Composer dependency conflict (project with package)

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

**I try to add package to starter-kit:**
`composer require akiraz2/Yii2-ticket-support "dev-master"`

Starter-kit: 
https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit

Package:
https://github.com/yii2-starter-kit/yii2-starter-kit

**Composer.json in my project:**

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.0",
    "ext-intl": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "^2.0.13",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^2.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-jui": "^2.0.0",
    "yii2-starter-kit/yii2-file-kit": "^2.1.0",
    "asofter/yii2-imperavi-redactor": ">=0.0.3@dev",
    "trntv/yii2-aceeditor": "^2.0",
    "trntv/probe": "^1.0",
    "trntv/yii2-glide": "^1.2",
    "trntv/yii2-datetime-widget": "dev-master@dev",
    "trntv/cheatsheet": "^0.1@dev",
    "trntv/yii2-command-bus": "^3.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.0",
    "almasaeed2010/adminlte": "^3.0",
    "npm-asset/font-awesome": "^5.0",
    "npm-asset/html5shiv": "^3.0",
    "npm-asset/jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3",
    "npm-asset/flot": "^3.2",
    "symfony/process": "^4.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
    "alexantr/yii2-elfinder": "^1.3",
    "trntv/sitemaped": "^0.1",
    "yii2mod/yii2-swagger": "^1.1",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widgets": "^3.4",
    "akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support": "dev-master",
    "rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome": "^3.4"
  },

  "require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "^2.0.0",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.4.0",
    "codeception/verify": "^0.3.1"
  },
```

---

**Composer.json in the package: `akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support`**

```
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0",
    "hashids/hashids": "^2.0",
    "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "*",
    "php-imap/php-imap": "^3.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-queue": "~2.0"
  },
```

**Error:**

```
  Problem 1
    - akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support dev-master requires rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome ~2.17 -> satisfiable by rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome[2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support dev-master requires rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome ~2.17 -> satisfiable by rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome[2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support dev-master requires rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome ~2.17 -> satisfiable by rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome[2.17.0, 2.17.1, 2.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support dev-master -> satisfiable by akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support[dev-master].
```

Comment: Please explain your issue more clearly

Answer (score -1):

Just read the error message: it tells you that `akiraz2/yii2-ticket-support` requires `rmrevin/yii2-fontawesome` with the version constraint `~2.17`, while your own application requires that same package with `^3.4`